# Can use gcp credentials for logging in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am developing a small in-house web application which will be soon running from google cloud platform. I am wondering if there is any Spring way to use the same gcp user credentials to login my application on cloud/premises too. In order to use high security and manage user who can login on system ? After verifying authorization of user using gcp api user are allowed to navigate menus ? Already firebase using same gcp credentials for accessing the collection.

I don't want to create a duplicate database for same users who already in GCP with credentials.

Comment: Do you want to reuse web user credential to perform API calls in GCP?

Comment: 1) I am logging into GCP console using my registered user credentials. (My organization specific email id). I want to get gcp user name in my spring boot application which is running inside cloud.

Comment: 2) Currently I am testing my spring application in a local environment, using gcp-key.json I am getting authorization for specific bucket to add a new file.  I want to authorize this application only accessed by gcp users even if run from outside gcp. Is there any api to pass user credentials to gcp and get authorization result outside gcp environment ? @guillaumeblaquiere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are on Google Cloud environment, you can rely on [Metadata servers](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview). The Google Cloud libraries leverage them automatically if you are in the cloud.

If not, the library will look in the well known location if you have user credentials stored locally (when you perform a `gcloud auth application-default login` you create a JSON file on your computer with your credentials).

You can override the whole process by using a [service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) (that I totally discourage to use because of security concerns) and storing the file path in the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variables.

That mechanism is named ADC (Application Default Credential) on Google Cloud.

*Note, you have also more complex authentication mechanism like impersonation and workload identity federation*

---

Therefore, if you want to run you app outside of Google Cloud, you have to provide a credentials: your user credentials, or a service account credentials (but if you use a service account key file, that means you also share a secret with your app. And if you share a secret, it's no longer a secret...)